# Better code to push notification: firestore - cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I made a cloud function (using google :() that sends push notifications when adding a document in firestore, but I have the error that you see in the image and the notifications do not arrive but I do not understand what may be wrong in my code, can someone help me?

[image]

mi code:

```
exports.cambiaColeccion = functions.firestore
  .document('sendMessage/{docId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => { 
    const nuevoMensaje= snap.data();
    
    console.log('id', nuevoMensaje);
    console.log('titulo', nuevoMensaje.titulo)
    enviaMensage();   
  });

  async function enviaMensage() {
    console.log('en enviaMensaje');
    const payload ={
        notification: {
            title: "Titulo del mensaje",
            body: "Texto del mensaje ... ",
            sound: 'default',
            badge: '1',
    }

    // Get the list of device tokens.
    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('FCMTokens').get();
    const tokens = [];
    allTokens.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
        tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
        // Send notifications to all tokens.
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);        
        //await cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
        console.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
    }
    return true
}

// Cleans up the tokens that are no longer valid.
function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {
    // For each notification we check if there was an error.
    const tokensDelete = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                const deleteTask = admin.firestore().collection('FCMTokens').doc(tokens[index]).delete();
                tokensDelete.push(deleteTask);
            }
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensDelete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a Promise in your Cloud Function, in such a way the Cloud Functions instance running your function does not shut down before your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

In your case you are not returning anything **in** the Cloud Function itself. Since async functions always return a Promise, you can adapt your code as follows:

```
exports.cambiaColeccion = functions.firestore
    .document('sendMessage/{docId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const nuevoMensaje = snap.data();

        console.log('id', nuevoMensaje);
        console.log('titulo', nuevoMensaje.titulo)
        return enviaMensage();
    });

async function enviaMensage() {
    console.log('en enviaMensaje');
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Titulo del mensaje",
            body: "Texto del mensaje ... ",
            sound: 'default',
            badge: '1',
        }
    }

    // Get the list of device tokens.
    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('FCMTokens').get();
    if (allTokens.size > 0) {  // allTokens is a QuerySnapshot
        const tokens = allTokens.docs.map(tokenDoc => tokenDoc.id);
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    }

}
```

---

Note that it would be good to add some try/catch block in order to capture and debug potential errors.

---

**Update following your comment on the `cleanupTokens` function.**

Your `cleanupTokens` function is correct. It is asynchronous since it returns a Promise (returned by `Promise.all(tokensDelete);`).

The way you call it should work correctly:

```
    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('FCMTokens').get();
    if (allTokens.size > 0) {  // allTokens is a QuerySnapshot
        const tokens = allTokens.docs.map(tokenDoc => tokenDoc.id);
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);        
        await cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much It worked, I still confused with promises and async/await :(, now I need to call the function: cleanupTokens(response, tokens) to delete the wrong tokens in the collection, how can I do that in the best way?, thanks a lot again

Comment: Hi @MarcosGalaviz, I've adapted the answer. Please upvote and accept the answer if it gave you the solution to your problem. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got this errror: cambiaColeccion
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined at cleanupTokens , but i solved like this: what do you think? await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
        .then(response => {
            cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
            console.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
        })